# How can I compile Valgrind on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, valgrind

How can I compile Valgrind on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FYI, Valgrind 3.6 (released October 21, 2010) officially supports Snow Leopard out-of-the-box.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html

Comment: 3.6.1 segfaults on Snow Leopard on 32-bit-only processor. If someone feels like reporting this upstream, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you've got XCode tools installed and an SVN client, here it goes.

Go to some directory you keep stuff in.
Checkout valgrind sources

```
svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/tags/VALGRIND_3_5_0 valgrind
```

Download Greg Parker's 10.6 patch

```
curl http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=36999 > 10.6.patch
mv 10.6.patch ./valgrind
```

Apply the patch

```
cd valgrind
patch -p0 < 10.6.patch
```

Compile valgrind

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

Install it

```
sudo make install
```

Run it

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes /tmp/a.out
```

Comment: Instead of "curl http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=36999 > 10.6.patch", substitute the link with "https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=36999" that use HTTPS! Version with HTTP doesn't run anymore

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the (almost) perfect answer of diciu. For compiling a 64 bit version of valgrind (required for 64 bit executables, aka. the standard in OS 10.6). You will need to run configure like this: ./configure --enable-only64bit

Answer (score 2):

diciu's answer worked flawlessly for a 32 bit build, but I couldn't get a 64 bit build working by adapting those instructions.

Found some other working instructions for getting a [64bit build of valgrind](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ValgrindOnSnowLeopard) though.

(replicated here, slightly adapted, since wget is not installed by default on os x)

```
svn co -r 11104 svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
cd valgrind
curl http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=40091 -o snow-leopard.patch
curl http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=40900 -o arc4random.patch
curl http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=42530 -o sidt.patch 
curl http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=42892 -o signal.patch
patch -p0 < snow-leopard.patch
patch -p0 < arc4random.patch
patch -p1 < signal.patch
cd VEX; patch -p0 < ../sidt.patch ; cd ..
touch darwin10-drd.supp
touch darwin10.supp
./autogen.sh || autoreconf -fvi
./configure --prefix=`pwd`/inst64 --build=amd64-darwin
make -j 8 && make install
```

Edit: in response to the comments, to have both 32 and 64 bit also do the following commands: (note that I have no need for a 32bit valgrind, so I didn't try this, but it should work)

```
make clean
 ./configure --prefix=`pwd`/inst32
make -j 8 && make install
```

Both will be located in inst32/ and inst64/ afterwards.

Comment: Does just the 64bit Valgrind build work for debugging 32bit binaries? Or you need to compile both versions? If so, could you modify your method so it compiles both versions and keeps both of them installed?

Comment: Switched the answer mark to this one, as it contains more up-to-date patches. Thank you!

Comment: on the third to last step: './autogen.sh || autoreconf -fvi'
I'm getting the error: 'configure.in:1817: the top level
Makefile.am:60: `pkglibdir' is not a legitimate directory for `DATA'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1'
Anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the --enable-only64bit configure flag avoided having to hack host_cpu="x86_64" into the configure script (using the patch diciu posted)

Answer (score 1):

> brew install valgrind

More info at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It isn't supported yet.

Comment: Some additional info. I read some people are compiling it using a patch available here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205241.

What I am requesting is the step-by-step process of applying the patch and compiling it.